# Утечка памяти при requests

Tags: python, утечка-памяти, requests

Нет мыслей почему утекает память. Прошу помощи.

```
import threading, requests, time
def dump_mem():
  s = open("/proc/self/status").readlines()
  for line in s:
    if line.startswith("VmRSS"):
      return line
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.send).start()
    def send(self):
        while True:
            print "Send.."
            self.response = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/").content
            print dump_mem()
            time.sleep(5)
for i in range(1, 5):
    threading.Thread(target=test).start()
```

Лог:

> Send..
>
> Send..
>
> Send..
>
> Send..
>
> VmRSS:     22620 kB
>
> VmRSS:     22644 kB
>
> VmRSS:     22660 kB
>
> VmRSS:     22664 kB
>
> Send..
>
> Send..
>
> Send..
>
> Send..
>
> VmRSS:     22732 kB
>
> VmRSS:     22732 kB
>
> VmRSS:     22736 kB
>
> VmRSS:     22740 kB

Comment: Прежде чем искать где у вас утекает память, приведите в порядок код. Для чего вы класс, в котором создается поток, помещаете в отдельный поток? И вообще для чего вам в данном случае нужен класс? По выводу который вы привели не видно что у вас утекает память. В python есть сборщик мусора, и пока он не запустится, память не очищается. Соответственно память может какое-то время тратиться, а потом освободиться. И в зависимости от создаваемых объектов, это могут быть не кБ, а даже мБ.